# how to get POST params with cherrypy

Tags: python, cherrypy

In my very simple cherrypy server I try to get the POST data of a request. I've looked around and came up with:

```
class UpdateScript:
    def index(self):
        cl = cherrypy.request.body.params
        print(cl)
        return ""
    index.exposed = True
```

But all it prints is {}. What am I missing?

Edit: My c# code for sending the post request is:

```
var client = new WebClient();
byte[] response = client.UploadData(UpdateScriptUrl, "POST", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("field1=value1&amp;field2=value2"));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify desired fields as positional parameters:

```
class UpdateScript:
    def index(self, field1, field2):
        ...
```

Or as keyword arguments:

```
class UpdateScript:
    def index(self, **kwargs):
        ...
```

Then, you will get what you want.

I tested it with following python script (*Python 2.7*):

```
import urllib
print urllib.urlopen('http://localhost:8080', 'field1=b&field2=c').read()
```

Comment: for me this only works with GET params, that is if I replace the url with "http:/localhost:8080/update_script?field1=3")

Comment: @Rolle, Which version of cherrypy do you use? (I used *3.2.2* to test)

Comment: Doh! My problem was I forgot to add a trailing "/" in the address. html is so... strange